# Yii2=>ActiveForm=> add "has-error" (or "has-access") by default on page open

Tags: yii2, active-form

I have a simple form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'answer-form',
    'action' => Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('test'),
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($user_answer, 'user_text')->textInput(['value' => $text])->label('Text') ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I want to show input with red color (div with class "has-error" by default)- like somebody added wrong data to the input. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?= $form->field($user_answer, 'user_text', [ 'options' => [ 'class' => 'has-error'])->textInput(['value' => $text])->label('Text') ?>
```